# call to 'pow' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, opencl

When i try to run the opencl kernel i get error:

```
 Error building: stringInput.cl:1:197: error: call to 'pow' is ambiguous
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/beignet/include/ocl_math.h:49:20: note: candidate function
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/beignet/include/ocl_math.h:148:19: note: candidate function
```

I'm using below c++ opencl code:

```
std::string kernel_code=
        "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){       "
        "   for(int i=0;i<20000;i++) {  "
        "   for(int j=0;j<20000;j++) {  "
        "   for(int k=0;i<20000;i++) {  "
        "   int d1 = sqrt(pow(A[i]-A[j],2)+pow(B[i]-B[j],2)+pow(C[i]-A[j],2)) "
        "   int d2 = sqrt(pow(A[i]-A[k],2)+pow(B[i]-B[k],2)+pow(C[i]-A[k],2)) "
        "   int d3 = sqrt(pow(A[k]-A[j],2)+pow(B[k]-B[j],2)+pow(C[k]-A[j],2)) "
        "       C[i+j]=A[i]+B[j]+k;     "
        "       }                       "
        "       }                       "
        "   }                           "
        "   }                           ";
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});
```

I'm using intel graphics card and opencl bingnet. Here when i don't use the pow or sqrt functions inside the kernel code, it runs ok. So how do i use other c++ functions in opencl kernel?

Comment: I think you cut off the part of the error message that tells you the reason. There should be some text after both `note: candidate function`

Comment: BTW, `x * x` is often more efficient than `pow(x,2)`.  There may be inaccuracies due to conversion between integer and floating point (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means there is not a version of the function which takes the type you are passing, but instead there are more than one version taking a type that could be converted to (like `float` and `double`). The compiler doesn't know which you want. There is not an `int` version of this function, but you are passing `int`. The error can be solved by casting the parameter to the function so it is clear (in this case, cast to `float` and cast the result back to `int`).